# ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

I am attempting to fine tune a `microsoft/DialoGPT-medium` model but experiencing some difficulties. Here is my error `ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits,past_key_values. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,attention_mask.`

Here is my code

```py
from datasets import Dataset
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, default_data_collator, AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

dataset = Dataset.load_from_disk('dataset')
print(dataset.column_names)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained('microsoft/DialoGPT-medium')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('microsoft/DialoGPT-medium')
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token


def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["prompt"], truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="pt", max_length=512)


tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns("prompt")


training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./model",  # The output directory
    overwrite_output_dir=True,  # overwrite the content of the output directory
    num_train_epochs=3,  # number of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,  # batch size for training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=64,  # batch size for evaluation
    eval_steps=400,  # Number of update steps between two evaluations.
    save_steps=800,  # after # steps model is saved
    warmup_steps=500,  # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    remove_unused_columns=False,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=default_data_collator,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets,
)
trainer.train()
trainer.save_model()
```

Comment: I assume that `dataset` has no `labels` column (i.e. the trainer isn't aware of your targets)? Can you show us a small sample `dataset`?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My dataset structure is:

DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['text', 'labels', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask'],
        num_rows: 44330
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['text', 'labels', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask'],
        num_rows: 11083
    })
})

Comment: @Alfi Barlow,  Have you managed to find an answer to your problem?